# Crash with white screen on android pytorch live

Tags: android, react-native, pytorch

#### Problem Area

react-native-pytorch-core (core package)

#### Steps to Reproduce

No bugs show up by following manual set up tutorial. But when I open the app, **the app close itself** with an instant white screen.
Two tutorials get the same result.
https://pytorch.org/live/docs/tutorials/get-started-manually/
https://pytorch.org/live/docs/tutorials/image-classification/

I think my connection is OK, beacuse [react native tutorial](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) works fine.
Systems: Ubuntu 20 + python 3.9.7

#### Expected Results

Get a functional application, not just an app icon.

#### Code example, screenshot, or link to repository

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/44538872/154845810-0abeb1d7-adef-4a41-8f47-e2799d251c6e.png

`npx react-native start` show something weired once I try to open app on my android device:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/44538872/154844991-4a53100c-879b-4f42-ba8a-9ae94930e27f.png

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu/Windows support is limited for Pytorch Live so far. Most features are built with full support on mac OS.

For your cases, it could lack the required dependencies for Pytorch Live to start, here is a few of them (obtained by running `npx torchlive-cli doctor`
on my mac machine, it may/may not work on Ubuntu)

```
Android SDK Manager
   path: /Users/yinglao/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager
   min version: 26.1.1
  ✅ version: 26.1.1

  Required Android Packages
     ✅ emulator 
     ✅ platform-tools 
     ✅ platforms;android-29 
     ✅ system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64 

  Installed Android Packages
     build-tools;29.0.2 (29.0.2)
     build-tools;32.0.0 (32.0.0)
     cmake;3.10.2.4988404 (3.10.2)
     emulator (31.2.8)
     ndk;20.1.5948944 (20.1.5948944)
     patcher;v4 (1)
     platform-tools (33.0.0)
     platforms;android-29 (5)
     platforms;android-30 (3)
     system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64 (12)
```